# Floating two lists on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

Have an image floated to the left and two unordered lists floated to the right. For some reason the lists float side by side and not on top of each other. I can't get list-2 to float underneath float 1.

Would anybody have any ideas?

```
<div class="container">

        <img src="yogapic1.png"/>

        <ul class="list-1">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Influences</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Andrews Video Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Photography</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class-"list-2">
            <li><a href="">Find Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>


    </div><!--container-->


.container {

max-width: 1075px;
margin: auto;

}

.container img {

float: left;

}

.list-1 {
    float: right;



 }

.list-2 {
    float: right;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a typo on list 2 (`-` instead of `=`).  If you also add `clear:right;` to the lists it should do what you want:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/nkYun/

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! God damn typo!

Comment: Happens to the best of us ;)

Comment: <----- Hit the tick, I need my fix

Comment: I don't have enough rep my man. Otherwise I would :) sorry dude. thanks for the help!

Comment: @s3king93 You don't need any rep to mark an answer as correct.

Comment: oh the tick sorry yeah I did it now :)

Answer (score 3):

```
.list-2 {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

`float: right` will, if there's enough room, put the element to the left of any other elements which have been floated to the right. To override that behaviour and guarantee that it will fall below the most recent `float:right` element you need to use `clear:right`.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the two lists in a single `div` element and float that to the right instead.

By floating the two lists individually, you are taking them out of the normal flow of the document, so they no longer force elements to appear below them.

Answer (score 0):

To float two lists on top of each other you simple need 3 steps:

1. The container should have position as relative `position:relative`
2. One of the 2 lists should be float for example to the right `float:right`
3. The second list should have position absolute `position:absolute` and the right of it is 0px so that it start from the right and be on the first list

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach. Sometimes trying to figure out what should be floated left, or what should be floated right can be confusing in code.  But if you have a general idea of what elements you want to be floated, (and perhaps later on you will decide to add more to that section), then contain the items within a parent container (in our case a div element with a css class called lists) and float the entire parent where you want to be.  Here's an example...

The CSS:

```
.container {
max-width: 1075px;
margin: auto;
}
.container img {
float: left;
}

.lists {
    float: right;
    border:solid 1px pink;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">

        <img src="yogapic1.png"/>

        <div class="lists">
        <ul class="list-1">
            <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Influences</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Andrews Video Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Photography</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class-"list-2">
            <li><a href="">Find Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>


    </div><!--container-->
```

And [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/VUASq/3/)

Notice too with this approach, you are no longer leaving the headache of ordering your lists with floats, but now, within this parent container, you can simply go into your HTML code and sore the lists, in any order you want them to be.

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

If you float list-2 to the right and clear: right too that should work. Like:

```
list-2 {
      float: right;
      clear: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to assign width to your list:

```
.list-1 {
    float: right;
    width:100%;
}
.list-2 {
    float: right;
    width:100%;
}
```

**Edit**

If you are giving same CSS to both lists, try something like this

```
.container ul{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```